# angular testing: How to look for text using angular testbed where the text is automatically added later outside the component

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How do I find this text 'This is example text'?

[image]

[image]

My angular test .spec file

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  
import { NgbModal, NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


////////// Test component
@Component({
  selector: 'app-one',
  template: `
  <div class="app-one">
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary open-popup" (click)="open(mymodal)">Open My Modal</button>
   
    <ng-template #mymodal let-modal>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is example text
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
  `
})
class AppOneComponent {
  title = 'appBootstrap';
  
  public closeResult: string = '';
  
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}
    
  open(content: any) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    });
  }
  
}
////

describe('test the popup', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        BrowserModule,
        NgbModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppOneComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
  });

  fit('should create popup and check the text', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppOneComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    // Select the button
    const buttonElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.open-popup');
    console.log('buttonElement', buttonElement);
    
    // Click the button
    buttonElement.click();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    const all = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;

    console.log('all', all);
    // Check for the modal text
    expect(all.querySelector('.modal-body')?.textContent).toContain('This is example text');
   
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
console.log('all', all);
```

Do you see the `.modal-body`? I think `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement` is only what's inside of the `app-root` in your 2nd picture from the developer tools.

Try using the `document` instead:

```
 const all = document;

 console.log('all', all);

 expect(all.querySelector('.modal-body')?.textContent).toContain('This is example text');
```